# Scanner module triggers call to node.admin.inc (require_once(), trying wrong path)

Tags: 7

All of a sudden, for no reason (favorite kind of problem) Scanner stopped working. I can access the configuration at `/admin/config/search/settings` but trying load the scanner at `admin/content/scanner` fatal errors:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: 
Failed opening required '/public_html/sites/all/modules/scanner/node.admin.inc'
(include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in 
/home/moondev/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 514
```

Notice the path is wrong where it's trying to load node.admin.inc

Scanner used to work as expected so I suppose either an update changed something or a conflict with another module (or it's settings) is happening.

Anybody experience something similar before, where a core include is trying to be loaded from the wrong path?

Comment: Drupal 7.14 Scanner 7.x-1.x-dev

Comment: Also just noticed http://drupal.org/project/scanner hasn't been worked on in quite a while...

Comment: It's almost definitely something to do with the `hook_menu()` implementation in the scanner module...I know it's the 'go to' answer, but have you tried clearing the cache and running cron?

Comment: Yes, but I like the simplicity, so I'll do it again to double check ;) It's weird how it was working previously too.

Comment: I've taken over maintainership of [Scanner](https://www.drupal.org/project/scanner). This should not effect the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a conflict with Administration Views (7.x-1.0-alpha1).

Disable admin views & functionality is restored. Not sure where the blame is yet because I haven't pinpointed the conflict. But it does make sense at face value because admin views replaces the `/admin/content` and scanner is located at `admin/content/scanner`

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer, so other users know you found a solution, and the question is not bumped to the front page, causing other uses to check your question thinking it needs to be answered. `:)`